# SQL Server Management Studio crashes during installation

Tags: sql-server, ssms

When i try to start instalation of SQL Server Management Studio i immediately got a crash that SQL Server Management Studio stopped working:

[image]

I cant get any log because the only button is to close the program

Does sb got problem like that?

Comment: what's your windows system environment ?

Comment: Can you translate that for us?

Comment: Have you checked Windows Event Viewer?

Comment: @KingJk - Windows 10

Comment: @scsimon - MSSM 17.6 stopped working, program stopped working properly because of a problem. Windows will close this program and inform you if there is any solution - sth like that

Comment: @Andrea - i dont have any information about SSMS in event viewer